# Spring Controller that accepts a HashMap of different type of Objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I need to make a POST Controller in Java Springboot which will accept a hashmap of objects.
The datatypes for each value in the key-value pair can be different

```
{
  "myFile" : MultipartFile
  "metadata" : Java POJO in string format
}
```

I have written the controller in this way:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile2(@RequestBody HashMap<String, Object> requestMap) {
    
    return new ResponseEntity<>("File uploaded successfully!", HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

How do I test this controller through POSTMAN? I have to bind an actual physical file and a json string to the RequestBody

Answer (score 0):

You can attach file in Postman.
[image]